# Adding additional anti-alias - to_do

Tags: gimp

How do I anti-alias text properly?  Here is the image ...normal text saved to a .png is jaggedy..even if you select anti-alias when creating it.  I don't know how they create this smoothness

[image: here]

Comment: I don't think this is programming related. I don't see a question here either.

Comment: Your question is really confusingly written (and it doesn't help that you keep editing it).  Are you trying to ask how to [outline text in GIMP](http://gimpology.com/submission/view/how_to_outline_text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "canonical" form of anti-aliasing is done by rasterizing at higher resolution than your target (e.g., at double the resolution in each dimension).

You then (in a virtual sense) overlay a grid on that at the target resolution. You count up the number of cells that have been filled, and pick your color based on that -- if all the cells are filled, you use the background color. If you none of the cells is filled, you use the background color. The crucial part: if some of the cells are filled, you pick a color in between the two, based on what percentage of those cells are filled. e.g., at 2x in each direction, with a black foreground and white background, you could pick black (all cells filled), white (no cells filled) or any of three intermediate shades of grey (1, 2, or 3 cells filled).

Those intermediate levels of grey (or whatever color then end up being, based on the foreground and background colors) are perceived as filling in the "jagged" edges. For example, a pixel that's 75% of the way from white to black will be perceived almost like a smaller pixel that's entirely black.

There are, of course, other anti-aliasing methods, mostly aiming to reduce the computational overhead of rasterizing at higher resolution. They're highly relevant for things like animation, but for producing a PNG file, this method is relatively simple and probably plenty fast.

Comment: thanks...turned out I had some unusable font...GIMP could not properly anti-alias it.Ended up just using a generic sans and it looked O.K....but atleast I know what the anti-alias button does now...thanks